# Test Promise with timeout Jest

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs, timeout

I have a simple code that resolves after 1 second:

```js
const promiseWithTimeout = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({id: 3});
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

I am trying to make a test using jest, however, using resolves or awaits makes it so the test passes even with the wrong expectation (unhandled rejection) .
And If I try to make a failing test, it passes even if the expectation fails

What I tried

```js
it("Should return the right ID", ()=>{
    expect.assertions(1);
    expect(promiseWithTimeout()).resolves.toEqual({id: 3});    // this one works fine
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)

  })
```

```js
it("Should return the right ID", ()=>{
    expect.assertions(1);
    expect(promiseWithTimeout()).resolves.toEqual({id: 4});    // this PASSES , but shows 
    // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expect(received).resolves.toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)

  })
```

I expected it to **fail** and show that the objects are different.

I also tried using then instead, but still same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options -

**return a promise from your test**

This will pass -

```js
it("should return the id", () => {
  return promiseWithTimeout().then(m => {  // return
    expect(m.id).toBe(3)                   // ✓
  })
})
```

This will fail -

```js
it("should return the id", () => {
  return promiseWithTimeout().then(m => {  // return
    expect(m.id).toBe(4)                   // ✕ id 4
  })
})
```

**async..await**

This will pass -

```js
it("should return the id", async () => {   // async
  const m = await promiseWithTimeout()     // await
  expect(m.id).toBe(3)                     // ✓
})
```

This will fail -

```js
it("should return the id", async () => {
  const m = await promiseWithTimeout()
  expect(m.id).toBe(4)                     // ✕ id 4
})
```

**.resolves and .rejects**

Notice you must `return` then expectant promise. This will pass -

```js
it("should return the id", ()=>{
  return expect(promiseWithTimeout()).resolves.toEqual({id: 3}) // ✓
})
```

This will fail -

```js
it("should return the id", ()=>{
  return expect(promiseWithTimeout()).resolves.toEqual({id: 4}) // ✕ id 4
})
```

**using jest.advanceTimersByTime**

Jest allows you to "fake" the timers so test can run fast while still ensuring async code is behaving correctly. In your testing file you must include `jest.useFakeTimers()` and your tests must use one of the techniques above. Here we `return` expectant promises -

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()

it("should return the id", () => {
  const p = promiseWithTimeout()
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)               // advance timers
  return expect(p).resolves.toEqual({ id: 3 }) // ✓
})
```

This will fail -

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()

it("should return the id", () => {
  const p = promiseWithTimeout()
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
  return expect(p).resolves.toEqual({ id: 4 })  // ✕ id 4
})
```

**using expect.assertions**

In many cases you do not need to specify `expect.assertions`. For example, when using the `.resolves` expectation, we will get an assertion failure if the promise rejects -

```js
const promiseWithTimeout = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject({ id: 3 })                       // reject
    }, 1000)
  })
}

jest.useFakeTimers()

it("should return the id", () => {
  const p = promiseWithTimeout()
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
  return expect(p).resolves.toEqual({ id: 3 }) // ✕ rejected
})
```

If you expect a promise to be rejected, use the `.catch method` and then add `expect.assertions` to verify that a certain number of assertions are called. Otherwise, a fulfilled promise would not fail the test -

```js
test('the fetch fails with an error', () => {
  expect.assertions(1)                      // expect assertions
  return fetchData().catch(e => expect(e).toMatch('error')) // ✓
})
```

For more information, see [Testing Asynchronous Code](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous) from the Jest docs.

Comment: Thanks for going in such details to explain, this was very clarifying. I didn't know you could return a promise to jest, and didn't think about assigning the promise to advance time later.